# Loop through json file appending key value to List

Tags: java, json, list

I am trying to loop through a `JSON` file and append the `value` each time to `patientList`. So far I believe I have done the hard part, however the simplest part seems to be taking a lot of time, that is appending the `values` to `patientList`. My `getJsonFile` method gets the path of the `JSON` file. The format of the `JSON` file is below. I am able to print `jsonArray` so I know I am good up to that point, but lost after that.

Json file.

```
[{"patient":1},{"patient":2},{"patient":3},{"patient":4},{"patient":5},{"patient":6},{"patient":7},{"patient":8},{"patient":9}]
```

getJsonFile method.

```
private List<Integer> getJsonFile(String path)
{
    List<Integer> patientList = new ArrayList<>();

    try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(path))
    {
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)jsonParser.parse(reader);
        System.out.println(jsonArray);


        // Update patientList
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++ )
        {

            patientList.add(jsonArray(i));
        }
    }
    catch(IOException | ParseException | NullPointerException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return patientList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JSONArray` contains objects: `{"patient":1}`

So you could not add `patientList.add(jsonArray(i));`

You have to access the int value inside that object:

```
JSONObject patient = jsonArray.getJsonObject(i);
patientList.add(patient.getInt("patient");
```

**Edit**

Well. You are using the simple-json library with quite limit feature and outdated. In this case you have to cast the data yourself:

```
JSONObject patient = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(i);
patientList.add((Integer)patient.get("patient");
```

I recommend you remove this lib and use existing JSON feature of Java. If you want more advance feature, Jackson/GSon is the library to use.

Comment: I am getting error `cannot resolve method getJsonObject` and the same thing for `getInt` method.

Comment: What's your `JSONObject` importing path? What's your JDK level

Comment: What do you mean by JDK level? And what do you mean by `JSONObject` importing path? This sounds very important.

Comment: I mean what's your full path of JSONObject? I'm refering to the default JAVA Object JSON which is javax.json.JSONObject

Comment: Oh I think I know what you mean. I am using `import org.json.simple.JSONObject;` I think javax is the library you are using. I do not know if I am correct with this.

Comment: This is what I am using https://jar-download.com/?search_box=json simple&p=1. I will download your version. Version 1.1.1 Looks like the same version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I still have problems but will work through it. I will look up Java JSON but it is very hard, I only could find simple JSON information. I am unaware of Java existing Json feature online everyone use simple JSON from what I see.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, this is the document [JSONObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) I guess it's lot easier than you thought.